# How to force to use new database when run python manage.py test in Django?

Tags: python, django, testing

When I type

```
python manage.py test
```

Sometimes I get asked if I want to delete the test database.

```
Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'test_replicate_live', or 'no' to cancel: yes
```

WHen I want to keep the test database, I know the command is :

```
python manage.py test --keepdb
```

I would like to know if there's a way to force the deletion of test database without waiting for the question to appear.

Sometimes I just know ahead of time, I want to delete the test database.

Is tehre a

```
python manage.py test --nokeepdb
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try

```py
python manage.py test --noinput
```

Which would suppress the prompt and default to destroying the test database.

It's documented here,
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database